# 18.04: Onboard webcam quantity very low compared to Windows 10

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, webcam, camera

Earlier I had Windows 10 installed in my laptop. Post system crash I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 replacing Windows 10.

Though the webcam is a 1.3 MP HD camera, the quality which I get in Ubuntu via Cheese is very low compared to the quality with the app which I used in Windows 10.

PFB the details

- Lenovo IdeaPad
- CPU: AMD Pro
- RAM: 4GB
- HDD: 520GB
- Camera: EasyCamera
- Previous  OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Current OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Also, in Windows 10, the battery had a standby of at least 6 to 7 hours, but now it lasts only for 4:50 hours for a full battery in Ubuntu.

Comment: 1) Which IdeaPad model? Pls find serial number sticker, copy the model number only, come back here and click [edit] to add into your question. 2) Battery issue should be in a different question. Pls cut it from this question and ask it in new question after searching for  TLP and other power management solutions.